# How to connect to a node server from a button press?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

Can I connect to a nodejs server with socket.io from a button press? I got my page for example `file:///home...site/index.html` and a server running on my local machine for example `localhost:8080`. Can i connect to the server from my file with when i call a function, using xmlhttprequest or other means? How? Got links/tutorials?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a very simple socket.io example on GitHub: [socketio-example](https://github.com/CoachEd/socketio-example)
Update the index.html page in this example to look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
        <script>
          var socket;
          function makeConnection() {
            socket = io();
            socket.on('welcome', function(data) {
              addMessage(data.message);
              // Respond with a message including this clients' id sent from the server
              socket.emit('i am client', {data: 'foo!', id: data.id});
            });
            socket.on('polo', function(data) {
              addMessage(data.message);
            });
            alert('connected.');
          }

          function addMessage(message) {
            var text = document.createTextNode(message),
                el = document.createElement('li'),
                messages = document.getElementById('messages');
            el.appendChild(text);
            messages.appendChild(el);
          }

          function marco() {
            socket.emit('marco');
          }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="makeConnection()">Connect</button>
        <button onclick="marco()">Marco!</button>
        <ul id='messages'></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will establish the socket.io connection when the user clicks *Connect*. Then you may click Marco! to send a message and receive the Polo! response.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this is not what i was looking for. Your site connects you to the node server instantly when you reach the page, I want to connect to it when i click a button.

Comment: That is easy enough to implement. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Edvin well, now you just added another emit but you still connects at `var socket = io()`. My real problem is that i want to connect to the server from another page which doesn't have the URL in the address bar, but instead reaches the server some other way on a javascript event, for example a button press

Comment: So what if we move that line inside the makeConnection() function but still declare it globally? That is basically what you are trying to do, right?